# How to pass props to modal in react navigation? Undefined params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, parameters, navigation

I am trying to navigate to a modal screen in React Native. I am able to navigate to the screen, but I am not able to pass any props.

This is how my stack is set up.

```
const MessagesStack = createStackNavigator(); 

function MainMessagesStackScreen() {   
return (
    <MessagesStack.Navigator>
      <MessagesStack.Screen name="Messages" component={MessagesView} options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </MessagesStack.Navigator>   ) }

const RootMessagesStack = createStackNavigator();

function RootMessagesStackScreen() {   
return (
    <RootMessagesStack.Navigator mode="modal">
      <RootMessagesStack.Screen 
        name="MainMessages"
        component={MainMessagesStackScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false}}
      />
      <RootMessagesStack.Screen 
        name="FullPageVideoScreen"
        component={FullPageVideoScreen}
        options={{ headerShown: false}}
      />
    </RootMessagesStack.Navigator>   ) }
```

In the MessagesView component, tapping a button leads to the following function:

```
  const goToVideo = (muxPlaybackId) => {
    console.log(muxPlaybackId);
    props.navigation.navigate(FullPageVideoScreen, {muxPlaybackId: muxPlaybackId}); 
  }
```

I then am able to go to the FullPageVideoScreen component. All the code works perfectly. However, no parameters are being passed.

This is the output of console.log(props).

```
Object {
  "navigation": Object {
    "addListener": [Function addListener],
    "canGoBack": [Function canGoBack],
    "dangerouslyGetParent": [Function dangerouslyGetParent],
    "dangerouslyGetState": [Function anonymous],
    "dispatch": [Function dispatch],
    "goBack": [Function anonymous],
    "isFocused": [Function isFocused],
    "jumpTo": [Function anonymous],
    "navigate": [Function anonymous],
    "pop": [Function anonymous],
    "popToTop": [Function anonymous],
    "push": [Function anonymous],
    "removeListener": [Function removeListener],
    "replace": [Function anonymous],
    "reset": [Function anonymous],
    "setOptions": [Function setOptions],
    "setParams": [Function anonymous],
  },
  "route": Object {
    "key": "FullPageVideoScreen-WmIBW-KYGYNBeOMq9kXZS",
    "name": "FullPageVideoScreen",
    "params": undefined,
  },
}
```

I would very much like to pass the muxPlaybackId value as a prop. However, right now, I am getting undefined. Do y'all have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid having a cluttered `navigate` function, you can try this approach.

```
const navObject = muxPlaybackId => {
      let details = {
      id: muxPlaybackId
    };
    return details;
 }

 const goToVideo = (muxPlaybackId) => {
    props.navigation.navigate({FullPageVideoScreen,navObject(muxPlaybackId)}); 
  }
```

In your `FullPageVideoScreen` component, you can access and set the props like this.

```
const [id, setId] = useState('')

useEffect(()=>{
setId(props.route.params.id)
},[])
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't really work for me. I get TypeErrors for both props.navigation.state.params and props.route.params.id because the values are undefined. I'm basically unable to pass the props.

Comment: That is strange, okay can you clear the `useState` and `useEffect` functions that I have in my answer and just conole.log(props.route.params) somewhere in your function?

Comment: How are you triggering `goToVideo()` ?

Comment: console.log(props.route.params) in FullPageVideoScreen is undefined. console.log(props.route.params) in MessagesView is also undefined.

Comment: I am triggering goToVideo using a TouchableOpacity function around an image. It ends up doing the job and sending me to the FullPageVideoScreen component.

Comment: Alright, can you check my answer again, I've made a little change in the `goToVideo`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212751/discussion-between-ajin-kabeer-and-vaibhav-verma).